How do I use postgresql crosstab to create a table of weekdays and appointments
I have a table with columns weekday, appointment, and appointment date for that week.
The table looks like this:
| Weekday | Appointment | Date           |
| Monday   | Doctor          | 2022-04-01 |
| Tuesday  | Dentist          | 2022-04-02 | ...
And I would to display the table with Weekdays as columns:
| Monday | Tuesday | ...
| Doctor   | Dentist   | ...
So far my query looks like this:
select * from crosstab (
$$
select apt."name" as "Appointment"
, initcap(to_char(to_timestamp(apt."date"/1000), 'day')) as "Weekday"
from appointments as apt
where date_trunc('week', now()) <= to_timestamp(apt."date"/1000) and to_timestamp(apt."date"/1000) < date_trunc('week', now()) + '1 week'::interval
$$,
$$
values ('Monday'::text), ('Tuesday'::text), ('Wednesday'::text), ('Thursday'::text), ('Friday'::text)
$$
) as ct("Appointment" text, "Monday" text, "Tuesday" text, "Wednesday" text, "Thursday"text, "Friday" text)
